# Execute only part of a function again

Tags: javascript

I'm making a browser game and the relevant part of my project is set up like this.
I have one namespace called Game that contains my game logic.
I have another namespace called Main (may change later) that handles key presses, and the control flow of the program.

In Game, I have a function init() which if simplified looks something like

```
const init = () => {
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    setInterval(repeatingFunc, 100);
};
```

If my guy dies in repeatingFunc, I clear the interval and the game is over.
In Main, I have something like

```
    document.onkeydown = (event) => {
        const keyCode = event.keyCode;

        if (Game.getIsGameOver() === true) {
            Game.setIsGameOver(false);
            Game.resetValues();
            Game.init();
        }

        if (Game.getIsPlaying() === false) {
            Game.setIsPlaying(true);
        }

        // More code that handles key presses, etc
    }
```

The game will prompt the user to press any key to begin again after the game is over, and if a key is pressed, Game.init() is called.

My question is as follows. For all calls to Game.init() excluding the initial call when the page is first loaded, i.e., for every game after the first game, I don't want func1() to execute. Suppose func1() is just something I need to happen the first time the page is loaded, and never again on subsequent game restarts. How do I execute all of init() again except for func1()?

edit: Of course I could just take func1() out of main and put it in a function that only gets called once, but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Add another `startGame()` method that doesn't contain `func1()`, and call it inside `init()`, and when the user wants to play again:

```
const startGame = () => {
  func2();
  func3();
  setInterval(repeatingFunc, 100);
};

const init = () => {
  func1();
  startGame();
};
```

And now you can call `Game.init();` the 1st time or `Game.startGame();` on replays.

**Option 2**

Use a flag for replays:

```
const init = (replay) => {
  replay || func1();
  func2();
  func3();
  setInterval(repeatingFunc, 100);
};
```

And now you can call `Game.init();` the 1st time or `Game.init(true);` on replays.